# cannot connect to "workspaceMount" at container launch from vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-devcontainer

using vscode and wsl2, I have tried to launch a container using the default method and no customization. This generated the same error as below.

so following vscode docs I set a `"workspaceMount"` in devcontainer.json

```
"workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspaces/myRepo,type=bind,consistency=delegated",
"workspaceFolder": "/workspaces",
```

I select `Reopen in container`, the launch sequence happens but an error is generated

```
a mount config is invalid, make sure it has the right format and a source folder that exists on the machine where the Docker daemon is running
```

the log error is

```
Command failed: docker run -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount source=d:\git\myRepo,target=/workspaces/myRepo,type=bind,consistency=delegated --mount type=volume,src=vscode,dst=/vscode -l vsch.quality=stable -l vsch.remote.devPort=0 -l vsch.local.folder=d:\git\myRepo --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-myRepo-a878aa9edbcf04f717c76e764dabcde6 -c echo Container started ; trap "exit 0" 15; while sleep 1 & wait $!; do :; done
```

by launching the container from docker desktop I can confirm

```
cd /workspaces
ls -l 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  3 11:48 myRepo
```

Is this issue due to owner `root:root` ?

Should this be changed by chown in the Dokerfile? if so could you provide a sample code to do this, is it by `RUN chown ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you followed the documentation in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced

The source should contains the subfolder "myRepo" and the target only "workspaces"

```
"workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/myRepo,target=/workspaces,type=bind,consistency=delegated",
"workspaceFolder": "/workspaces",
```